# To guarantee MUTEX, the semaphore operations need to be atomic

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, mutex, semaphore

If the Wait and Signal are implemented as follows:

```
void Wait (Semaphore S) {
while (S.count <=0){}
S.count = S.count -1;
}

void Signal (Semaphore S){
S.count = S.count+1;
}
```

Can anybody explain me please, when can both Threads T1 and T2 enter a critical section guarded by a single mutex semaphore as a result of a lack of atomicity ?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that T1 is running.

It enters wait on the semaphore, checks that count is less or equal to zero, which we assume is false - the loop ends.

Now the scheduler halts the thread and passes control to T2. Of course it does the same thing, then decreases the counter and is halted by the scheduler, control is handed back to T1.

T1 continues with decreasing the value (no checking this time, the loop is over!) and exits wait.

The control is passed to T2 which, also exits wait.

Now they have both entered critical section.

Comment: You mean, if the scheduler passes control to T2, it will **increase** the counter, T2 will be halted by the scheduler and at the same the control will be given back to T1. T1 continue to **decrease** the counter, T2 will increase it... and so both will enter the critical section !?

Comment: Why would they increase them? They both enter `wait`. The trick is that one of them is halted before decreasing the counter, thus allowing the other one to pass through the loop. Now they can, in whatever order, decrease the counter and execute the critical section, The order in `signal` doesn't matter, the damage is already done by then.